# Create index on type *and* label when using Tinkerpop3?

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Tinkerpop 3 introduces the great concept of labels. We are heavily using this feature where it identifies the schema used.

However, i see no support for labels when using indexes:

`Graph#createIndex(String key, Class<E> elementClass)`

Is there any way to create label specific indexes?

**UPDATE**

I am using TinkerGraph (in memory reference implementation).

Comment: Indexing is vendor-specific. Are you using TinkerGraph directly or any other GraphDB?